# Unexpected automatic rounding of values

Tags: java

I converted all the relevant variables to double but the result is only shows as a whole number!

```
package StatsCalc;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        double game_played = 100;
        int no_array = 5;
        int array [] = new int [no_array];
        double no_win = 0;
        double stat = 0;
        int a = 0;

        boolean win = true;
        boolean win_f [] = new boolean [(int) game_played];

        Random r = new Random ();

    while (a < game_played){
        for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++){

            array [i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;

            if (array [i] % 2 == 0){
            }else win = false;

            }

        if (win == true){
            win_f [a] = true;
        }



    a++;
    win = true;     
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < win_f.length; i++){
        if (win_f[i] == true){
            no_win++;
        }
    }
     game_played) * 100;

    System.out.println("Your chance of winning is " + stat + "% for " + no_array + " number of arrays.");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Which variable are you expecting to not be a whole number? You print `stat` which you set to 0 then never touch it again and then you print `no_array` which you set to 5 then never change it.

Comment: It's look like some code you lost, what is mean "} game_played) * 100;" ? Where is setting of stat variable?

Comment: As a note, to receive the maximum and quickest amount of help, **please format your code cleanly**.

Comment: Okay, so, that's what you did, and that's what it shows.  What's the question?

Comment: When you have a debug in your code, this is a good time to step through your code in your debugger and work out what your code is really doing.  There is a lot of code here which doesn't do anything useful and I would remove as much as you can.

Comment: ok guys i thought I cropped out some of my empty space but I cropped out my

Comment: stat = (no_win / game_played) * 100;

Comment: along with it. but I figured out that the whole thing was supposed to return 0, like the guy said below so thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will print out :

Your chance of winning is 0.0% for 5 number of arrays.

Your stat variable is a double but you are initializing it here:

```
    double stat = 0;
```

and you dont change it.